# Jquery, $ajax and Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

i have this code on my site:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://www.rp-online.de/cmlink/top-news-1.2513701',
        cache : false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('title').text();
            console.log($(xml).text());

            var as = $(xml).find('description').eq(1).text();
            $('#av').append(as);
        },
        error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            console.log(textStatus);
            $("#result").html(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

For now, this code works, and its used to get data from another website ( RSS feed ).

Everything looks good on Desktop, IOS, but NOT on android.
When i turn on Chrome and mobile emulation, i see this in console:
parseerror.
Does anybody know a solution ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

your Jquery code Works fine. I tested it on my computer using an Android emulator with both the native and chrome browser and here what I have[image]

maybe you have a problem in your HTML. check if you are not replicating the "ids"

```
<html>  
    <head>  
    <title></title>  
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://www.rp-online.de/cmlink/top-news-1.2513701',
    cache : false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('title').text();
        console.log($(xml).text());

        var as = $(xml).find('description').eq(1).text();
        $('#av').append(as);
    },
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        console.log(textStatus);
        $("#result").html(textStatus);
    }
});

    </script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div id="av"></div>

    </body>  
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, that code above will only work for Ipad, Nexus 7, but not for other devices. For Ipad header is:

Status Code:200 OK
Content-Type:application/rss+xml;charset=utf-8

And for Iphone:
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type:text/html